# Save result of many queries in a single array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I have the following problem, it is possible to save the result of each of the queries in an array (query 1, query2, query3).
This is the function in my model:

```
function get_query($year){

$query1 =$this->db->query("select count(*) as c from table where MONTH(date) = 1 AND YEAR(date) ='".$year."'");
$query2 =$this->db->query("select count(*) as c from table where MONTH(date) = 2 AND YEAR(date) ='".$year."'");
$query3 =$this->db->query("select count(*) as c from table where MONTH(date) = 3 AND YEAR(date) ='".$year."'")


}
```

And I need to receive that array in the driver in json format.

```
function query(){

        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $data = $this->mymodel->get_query($year);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

This is my controller:

Comment: `$array[] = query::result`
When you have empty brackets, it will start with `0`.

Comment: What about 1 query `select count(*), month(date) ... MONTH(date) between 1 and 3 ... group by month(date)`? You also are open to SQL injections. Your `get_query` still needs to return something.

Comment: @chris85 This query returns an amount, for example 5, that number 5 together with the values of the other queries I want to store in an array

Comment: @KoenHollander I do not understand the answer very well

Comment: What I wrote doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

this is not answering your question but i believe that it is showing you a solution to the issue, in the model, try

```
if (is_number($year))
{
   $query = $this->db->query("select sum(if(month(date)=1 and year(date) = {$year},1,0)) as month1,
         sum(if(month(date)=2 and year(date) = {$year},1,0)) as month2,
         sum(if(month(date)=3 and year(date) = {$year},1,0)) as month3
       from `table`");
       return $query->first_row();
}
```

that should get it all into one query and one row for you.
note that is_number provides some injection prevention.

to answer **your** question, you would need to make a new array with keys and  values, or create a standard class that holds all the data and return it to the controller.  I think this solution is nicer because you are doing one query and not three.